# Convert json file into string

Tags: c#, json

I'm trying to capture the names and values of all nodes coming from a random Json file that I don't know its structure (uploaded by the user).

I can loop through a json string and get the info I need but how do I start from a file? If I want to deserialize it I believe I need a class to hold that data (and I don't know the file structure).

Here's how I loop through elements from a json string:

```
   string json = @"{
       'CPU': 'Intel',
       'PSU': '500W',
       'Drives': [
         'DVD read/writer'
         /*(broken)*/,
         '500 gigabyte hard drive',
         '200 gigabype hard drive'
       ]
    }";

        JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(json));
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.Value != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Token: {0}, Value: {1}", reader.TokenType, reader.Value);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Token: {0}", reader.TokenType);
            }
        }
```

How do I read from a file and set it as a string that can be handled by the code above? It sounds like a basic question but I'm still struggling with this after several hours. All I've seen expects that you know the structure of the Json file and I don't in this case.

Comment: `string json = File.ReadAllText(path)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the exact use case that `dynamic` and `ExpandoObject` were made for! Here you can deserialize the JSON to an object, then traverse the object's properties (look up online how to work with ExpandoObjects).

```
var expandoConverter = new ExpandoObjectConverter();
dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(json, expandoConverter);
```

Or, if you were just looking to read the json from disk as a string, then use `string json = File.ReadAllText(filePathAndName)`;

The above code snippet requires installing the package NewtonSoft.

Comment: Thanks @ErikE. That is what I'm looking for (I should have been more specific in my question). In fact, I need to modify some of those values as I loop through the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Eriks answer was great to mention the `ExpandoObject`, `dynamic` and `File` call.  It got my +1.

I'm adding to ErikEs answer to include the package and include details required for a minimal running program.

This code was in my `Program.cs` file for a Console App project type in Visual Studio 2017.  You should also run `install-package newtonsoft.json` in the Package Manager Console.  This command will load `newtonsoft.json.11.0.1` pakcage.  .Net Framework was 4.6.1.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;
using System.Dynamic;
using System.IO;

namespace ReadJson
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string filePath = "<full path to json file>";
            string json = File.ReadAllText(filePath);

            var expandoConverter = new ExpandoObjectConverter();
            dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(json, expandoConverter);
            //do more with your dynamic object here...
        }
    }
}
```